# Regex pattern for embedded date

Tags: regex, python-re

I'm looking for a regex pattern that will help me detect the date an app was last updated. However, the text from web scraping looks like this:

```
A lot of text here etc etc.Updated onMar 8, 2023#6and more text here with no spaces
```

I would like to get "Mar 8, 2023", but I'm finding it hard to extract from the surrounding text since there are no spaces.

I'm trying with

```
pattern = r"Updated on\.* \d+\.* 2023"
```

But it hasn't worked so far.

Thanks.

Comment: You can just take a range of 11 or 12 chars starting from on, because that's the standard length that that date will have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

```
pattern = r"[a-zA-Z]{3} \d+, 2023"
re.findall(pattern, beautiful_soup)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
(?<=Updated on)([a-zA-Z1-9, ]*\d+)(?=\D)
```

`(?<=r)d` matches a **d** only if is preceded by an **r**.

`d(?=r)`  matches a **d** only if is followed by **r**.

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/TriMIl/1)

Comment: Thanks. It didn't work in this string: "m.Updated onFeb 28, 2023BusinessData" (sic); but my pattern did. Do you know why?

Comment: In your text there is a #, so I was thinking # will always there

Comment: I made an update can you have a look

Answer (score 0):

I found all dates in a string with a three character month followed by the day and a four digit year

```
txt="""A lot of text here etc etc.Updated onMar 8, 2023#6and more text here with no spaces"""
pattern = re.compile(r'\w{3}\s\d{1,2},\s\d{4}')
print(pattern.findall(txt))
```

output

```
['Mar 8, 2023']
```